# Print daily blank spaces in FullCalendar

Tags: css, printing, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

Is there some way in FullCalendar to print as it appears on the screen?

When viewing on screen, the time slots are uniform and free time slots (no event) shows as blank.
[image]

However, when printing, the events are collapsed, so you can go from 10 AM to 5 PM with no visual representation of the free time in between the events.
[image]

If I remove `<link href='fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />` it gets me very close to what I want, but the main problem is that the entire calendar doesn't print - only the part visible within the parent `<div>` tag prints.

I'm using FullCalendar v3.10.0, but I can upgrade to something more recent if that will solve the problem.

Comment: Printing from a browser will only print what's visible in an inner scroll area (minus anything excluded by print CSS). That's not a problem with fullCalendar specifically. If you made your calendar's body always be full height then it might work. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/contentHeight (I think it's the "auto" setting you need)

Comment: @ADyson yeah, I saw the auto option, but that messed up the format on the screen. If there was some option to set height: 'auto' only for printing, that might give me what I want, or just have have the print.css include the blank times.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. If I have time later I'll look into whether that might be achievable.

Comment: @ADyson Actually, it might be more complicated: if height: 'auto' is set and the calendar extends beyond 1 printed page, no events are printed - just an empty calendar (after removing the print.css file), so that problem would also need to be addressed.

Comment: Ok so I just made a demo. I can't reproduce that issue. This demo does not have the print.css included, contentHeight: "auto" is on, and there is no issue, as far as I can see, with a multi-page printout in an agenda view: http://jsfiddle.net/6rtb20d8/1/ (I tested in the latest Chrome on Windows 10).

Comment: @ADyson Did you try printing your jsfiddle with the daily view? That reproduces it for me using Firefox 68.0.1 on MacOS. It actually works fine in Chrome and Safari on MacOS, just not in FF.

Comment: I did try that, and there was no problem. Unfortunately, with printing you are always somewhat at the mercy of the browser's implementation and/or even your printer drivers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197179/discussion-between-edward-and-adyson).